# can we apply .skin file themes to client controls(Html)

Tags: asp.net

We can apply styles through .css by giving property class name:

Ex: `<input type="text" class="StyleSheet" id="txtName" />`

But in server control(asp) there is a property called SkinId, by this way we can access.

Ex: `<asp:TextBox SkinID="DataListColor" ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

So, can we apply styles to html controls through .skin files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, skins can only be applied to server controls.